# How to set the ActionBar title in middle instead of the default left aligned position?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

Trying to set the `ActionBar` title in middle instead of the default left aligned position. To do so, based on other answers this is what I've done:

```
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarDownloads);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
    }
```

*actionbar_layout.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Downloads"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, this does not produce the intended result *(ie this renders the text however still is left aligned)*, what's wrong with this approach and how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to add getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled();  before  getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this use custom `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ar_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

now in java file

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ar_toolbar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
 mTitle.setText("Nilesh Rathod");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: @Nilesh, Thanks for the quick approach, but I can't use the toolbar inside a custom layout file, there are other elements that depends on the Toolbar that's inside the Activity, ie I do have a custom SmartTabLayout(https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) in action along with the Toolbar , so can't go with a Toolbar inside a custom layout file for the actionbar :/

Comment: Ok , I got it ! , lemme try :)

Comment: @OBX let me know in case of any query

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach use `android:layout_gravity="center"` on your `TextView` and hide default title using below code after that initialize your `TextView` and set value

**Inside your activity:**

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
toolbar_title.setText("My Custom center title");
```

**Custom toolbar XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Toolbar Title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Toolbar` in your `xml` file and you can use `TextView` inside `Toolbar`. You can add custom view into `Toolbar`. Once you done with xml file then you can define `Toolbar` into `Activity` class.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="#ffffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Downloads"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

   //Rest of your code

</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity class you can define as

```
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ar_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Toolbar` for this. Just use a theme like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` with `ActionBar` in your activity and use the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
    }
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back_txt"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Back" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Downloads"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filter_btn"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```