# Tile not getting center in Collapsed toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I tried setting `collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

and almost all available links on INTERNET but i am not able to put the title in center of `toolbar`.

[image]

plz help !

Comment: check this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558006/how-to-set-the-actionbar-title-in-middle-instead-of-the-default-left-aligned-pos/46558058#46558058

Comment: @Prem : i tried using all the code available in that link but it doesn't work :,(

Comment: can u share your code with me so i can help you

Comment: the main xml: https://paste.ofcode.org/QZrfHxF3QvQCZudyDG3Gin , internal xml of main xml : https://paste.ofcode.org/qY8VhPYkwhTvcB9g8XAaRk , java code: https://paste.ofcode.org/cAgnkNnwshMWhUfnHy4MQM

Comment: @Prem : are these links fine for you as i have pasted the exact code on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your `Toolbar` like this

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

in your activity file change like this

```
toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
mTitle.setText("PREM");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: i did it but due to hamburger icon , its shifting to right

Comment: @GuneetKaur got the solution but its just temporary solution

Comment: plz tell me the solution ?

Comment: @GuneetKaur **due to hamburger icon** you title not in center just check updated ans with giving **android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"**

Comment: Thanks, its in center now .

Comment: @GuneetKaur happy to help you

Comment: This solution works but now whenever I change orientation, I see the title set shift before settling back to the assigned margin. Anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

To center the text in the toolbar you need to use a custom toolbar with a textview inside it rather than using android:title=""

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You can apply the same logic in a collapsible toolbar.