# Center Toolbar title in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, androidx

I getting some weird behaviour trying to get my Toolbar title centered when placed inside CollapsingToolbarLayout. Instead, it shows the title to right. This is my xml

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/headerImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/text_size_small"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:text="@string/user_tracking"
                        android:textColor="@color/tcBlack"
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        style="@style/TcTextAppearance.Bold.Toolbar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

and in code, I set setDisplayShowTitleEnabled and setDisplayHomeUpEnabled both to false but still am not able to get the title of the toolbar centred. I need help

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47301097/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod, thanks for the link. That solution works but now whenever I change orientation, I see the title set shift before settling back to the assigned margin.